# Filter Firebase Firestore entries based on category

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, filter, google-cloud-firestore

I need to filter entries based on their category. This is the error I get.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of null at
> VueComponent.filteredItems

Vue component:

```
<v-card
      v-for="product in filteredItems"
      :key="product.id"
      class="mx-auto"
      max-width="344"
    >
 [...]
```

Computed:

```
...mapState('products', ['products']),
        filteredItems() {
          let filtered = this.products
          if (this.search) {
            filtered = this.products.filter(
              item => item.name.category.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.search.toLowerCase()) > -1
            )
          }
          return filtered
        }
      },
```

export default:

```
export default {
      props: {
        filterCategory: String
      },
      data: () => ({
        search: 'Personal',
```

Firestore JSON entry:

```
name: {action:"button",  category: "Personal" [...]
```

How to fix the error?

Comment: did you try `console.log(this.products)`?

Comment: Yes, all products are there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of null at VueComponent.filteredItems

it's saying that this.products is null at some point. It happens when you set default state to null and then on the first load, when data is not yet fetched from firebase/api, its still null. so a simple solution would be

```
if (this.search) {
        filtered = this.products && this.products.filter(
          item => item.name.category.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.search.toLowerCase()) > -1
        )
      }
```

Please check with this code.